# Does Apple Allow to use JavaScript context in App Store?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiwebview, app-store, appstore-approval

I'm working on a project in which, I have `UIWebView` where I need to call some `JavaScripts` on a webpage in this `UIWebView` and that particular `JavaScript` will call my `Objective-C` **native** method.

To do that, I'm fetching `context` from `UIWebView` and setting my `Objective-C` object to the `context` and this object I'm fetching in `JavaScript`and In JavaScript, object I'm calling a `Objective-c` with this function/method.

Here is the code I'm using to do above,

```
JSContext *context = nil;
    context = [_webView valueForKeyPath:@"documentView.webView.mainFrame.javaScriptContext"];

// enable error logging
[context setExceptionHandler:^(JSContext *context, JSValue *value) {
    NSLog(@"WEB JS: %@", value);
}];

context[@"MyObj"] = self;
```

So my simple question is, whether this way of doing this is ok, in terms of Apple Store. I mean, is there something that can cause my app to get rejected my **Apple** for **App Store**?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is nothing currently in the App Store guidelines that would prohibit what you intend to do.

The ability to initiate functionality from a web server, even if it's via JavaScript in a web view, is common behavior.

Your app is run in a sandbox, so any security concerns are limited to your app. You're not adding code to your app, which is strictly prohibited. You're simply including functionality that may be called at a later time.

Comment: thank you for quick reply Adams, if it ok then believe me it'd be such a great relief to me.

Comment: @SuryakantSharma, How did the app submission go? Was it approved?

Comment: @prijupaul It was a iOS `SDK` I was working on those days and many app using that now and no body complain anything about it so far...so it's good.

Answer (score 1):

The short answer is that it depends on who reviews your app.

I have apps that do something very similar, and they were approved without issue. I have other apps rejected for doing the same thing because the JavaScript was considered "downloaded executable code".

To answer your specific question, I do not believe what you are doing in your Objective-C code will cause a problem with Apple's review, but depending on the source of the JavaScript, that may.

Bottom line is that Apple's review guidelines are still interpreted by humans at Apple, and that interpretation is not perfectly consistent.

Comment: Picciano thank you for quick reply, I'm getting 'JavaScript' as a API call response and what it does is "simple clicks on buttons present in the Web pages and Call 'Objective-c' native function accordingly".